# Unity3d Updating position with animation simultaneously

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have an animation for humanoid models to simulate climbing. I have been looking for a way to stimulate this animation when the model comes next to the window. I used the triggers to determine where the model is and it worked. However, when I execute the animation, the position of the model is not being updated according to the animation. I am using offmesh links and nav mesh agent and I disable nav mesh agent when the model triggers. How can I use the animation and provide the update simultaneously?

[Animation Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6QXe.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the animation should take care of the movement. You should control that somewhere else. You could make the animation climb from y = 0 to 5 but then it won't work if your ladder is at y = 3.

You'd better have a method that is called from the animation using AnimationEvent so that when you trigger the animation, it also triggers a movement of the object upwards/downwards regardless of the current position of the object. It would simply use Translate and disabled input until the animation ends.